# Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command) always return 1

Tags: java, shell

i am trying to run the following code on my mac

```
 String command = "find /XXX/XXX/Documents/test1* -mtime +10 -type f -delete";

Process p = null;
p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command);
p.getErrorStream();
int exitVal = p.waitFor();
```

and exitVal is always 1 and it won't delete the files 
Any Idea??

Comment: Try using the full path to `find`

Comment: Have you tried reading the `Process`'s `InputStream` or `ErrorStream`?  You should also be be using a `ProcessBuilder`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From my experimentation, `find` will return `1` when it fails to find any results (`find: /XXX/XXX/Documents/test1*: No such file or directory`)

First, you should really be using `ProcessBuilder`, this solves issues with parameters which contain spaces, allows you to redirect the input/error streams as well as specify the start location of the command (should you need it).

So, playing around with it, something like this, seemed to work for me (MacOSX)...

```
ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder(
        new String[]{
            "find", 
            "/XXX/XXX/Documents/test1",
            "-mtime", "+10",
            "-type", "f",
            "-delete"
        }
);
pb.redirectErrorStream(true);
try {
    Process p = pb.start();
    InputStream is = p.getInputStream();
    int in = -1;
    while ((in = is.read()) != -1) {
        System.out.print((char)in);
    }
    int exitWith = p.exitValue();
    System.out.println("\nExited with " + exitWith);
} catch (IOException exp) {
    exp.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: This works great just added before int exitWith = p.exitValue(); i added p.waitFor() to prevent exception. thanks a lot