# Passing command prompt functions from java

Tags: java, windows, command-line

I want to get the result of windows command prompt function from Java.

Java code:

```
Process process2 = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd /c getmac");
```

Are there any alternative libraries available other than `Runtime`?

Comment: Consider Apache Commons Exec as @v.ladynev suggested. And check this SO post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6295866/how-can-i-capture-the-output-of-a-command-as-a-string-with-commons-exec

Comment: @Aurelien , I like your comment. post it as an answer

Comment: @VINOTH KUMAR , is your question about general executing commands or getting the mac address specifically ? Aurelien suggested this http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-get-mac-address-in-java/ which is much cleaner and not platform specific , but I think he removed his comment.

Comment: Use a ProcessBuilder and redirect the error stream through the input stream and then read the Process's InputStream, something similar to [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34537130/runtime-getruntime-execcommand-always-return-1/34537482#34537482)

Comment: @MadProgrammer        It works fine. I'm working on a Java program to create a file which get the user name of the system and store it to the text file. when I make it into executable using Inno setup in Netbeans. It creates the text file in the installation folder. But I need to be created where the executable exists. In case pendrive, when my application executes it should create file in the pendrive not on the installation directory. How to overcome this?

Comment: @VINOTHKUMAR Set the working directory of the `ProcesBuilder`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [Apache Commons Exec](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-exec/tutorial.html). It can be used to get a console output of the running process.

A part of code from a real project

```
    private final Executor executor = new DefaultExecutor();

    private final ExecuteWatchdog watchDog = new ExecuteWatchdog(ExecuteWatchdog.INFINITE_TIMEOUT);

    private final ProcessDestroyer shutdownHookProcessDestroyer = new ShutdownHookProcessDestroyer();

    private final DefaultExecuteResultHandler resultHandler = new DefaultExecuteResultHandler() {
        @Override
        public void onProcessFailed(ExecuteException ex) {
            super.onProcessFailed(ex);
            LOG.error("Error executing xxx.exe", ex);
        }
    };

    public void startInSaveRecordMode(Long callId, File pathToResult) throws IOException {
        CommandLine commandLine = createModeUserPasswordCommandLine(SAVE_RECORD_MODE_COMMAND)
                .addArgument(ValidationUtil.toString(callId)).addArgument(
                        ValidationUtil.toString(pathToResult));
        execute(commandLine);
    }

    private void execute(CommandLine commandLine) throws IOException {
        Assert.notNull(pathToProcess);
        executor.setWatchdog(watchDog);
        executor.setProcessDestroyer(shutdownHookProcessDestroyer);
        executor.setStreamHandler(createStreamHandler());
        if (LOG.isDebugEnabled()) {
            LOG.debug("Executing " + commandLine);
        }
        executor.execute(commandLine, resultHandler);
    }

    private CommandLine createModeUserPasswordCommandLine(String mode) {
        Assert.hasLength(sensormUser);
        Assert.notNull(sensormPassword);
        return createCommandLine().addArgument(mode).addArgument(sensormUser);
    }

private CommandLine createCommandLine() {
    return new CommandLine(pathToProcess);
}

private ExecuteStreamHandler createStreamHandler() {
    OutputEventsHandler eventsHandler = new OutputEventsHandler(eventsQueue);
    SensormLogHandler errorLogHandler = new SensormLogHandler(LOG, Level.ERROR);
    return new PumpStreamHandler(eventsHandler, errorLogHandler);
}

public int waitFor() throws InterruptedException {
    resultHandler.waitFor();
    return resultHandler.getExitValue();
}
```

Comment: thanks. It works fine.    I'm working on a Java program to create a file which get the user name of the system and store it to the text file.   when I make it into executable using Inno setup in Netbeans. It creates the text file in the installation folder. But I need to be created where the executable exists. In case pendrive, when my application executes it should create file in the pendrive not on the installation directory.  How to overcome this?

Comment: @VINOTHKUMAR You are welcome. Sorry, I can't help you with this problem.